# Time units while configuring systemd.service

Tags: systemd

The current query focuses on [RuntimeMaxSec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RuntimeMaxSec=) but need not limit to that alone. A better guidance in a wider perspective is much appreciated. This configuration `RuntimeMaxSec` mentions the time unit as seconds in the name, but by experience and few other references, I had found the value of `5min` to work fine.

All attempts to find a clear documentation on time units did not help, but something close was found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#RuntimeWatchdogSec=). Though its not exactly connected, but part of the documentation seems to apply to the original field in question.

Please clarify if there is any general documentation or guideline around this which helps with all possible time units and formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`systemd.time`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Parsing%20Time%20Spans):

> #### Parsing Time Spans
>
> When parsing, systemd will accept the same time span syntax.
> Separating spaces may be omitted. The following time units are
> understood:
>
> - usec, us, µs
> - msec, ms
> - seconds, second, sec, s
> - minutes, minute, min, m
> - hours, hour, hr, h
> - days, day, d
> - weeks, week, w
> - months, month, M (defined as 30.44 days)
> - years, year, y (defined as 365.25 days)
>
> If no time unit is specified, generally seconds are assumed, but some
> exceptions exist and are marked as such. In a few cases "`ns`",
> "`nsec`" is accepted too, where the granularity of the time span
> permits this. Parsing is generally locale-independent, non-English
> names for the time units are not accepted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That greatly helps removing all confusions.